# How to get the summ of all values

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this piece of code PL/SQL code in a procedure

```
for rec in(select t.val, t.cat from table t where a=1)
Loop
v:=(rec.val*rec.cat)/2;
end Loop;
```

How I can get the sum of all 'v' values?

Comment: v:=v + (rec.val*rec.cat)/2; ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create the sum in another variable, named tempSum

```
DECLARE
tempSum number (6);

tempSum := 0;

for rec in(select t.val, t.cat from table t where a=1)
Loop
v:=(rec.val*rec.cat)/2;
tempSum := tempSum + V;
end Loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way:

```
select sum(t.val * t.cat / 2) into l_val_cat_sum from table t where a = 1;
```

Comment: I will need the single results line by line as well :) Can I sum them somehow inside the loop?

Comment: You can, but for what? Use something like select t.val * t.cat / 2 as value, sum(t.val * t.cat / 2) over () as summ. Let Oracle do work instead of you.